# Rails eager loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eager-loading

HI,
I have a Test model, which has_many questions, and Question, which has_many answers...
When I make a query for a Test with :include => [:questions, {:questions => :answers}] ActiveRecord makes two more queries to fetch the questions and then to fetch the answers - it doesn`t join them!!! When I do the query with :joins ActiveRecord makes the query, but later when I need the Test.questions or Test.questions.answers ActiveRecord makes again those 2 extra queries!!! And later when I enumerate the questions or answers in the log I see other queries for each object, but it has Cache tag...

Is this normal?

Comment: Just `:include => { :questions => :answers }` will do, no need to specify `:questions` twice.

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208636/rails-include-vs-joins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with shteef, what happens when you do the following:

```
:include => { :questions => :answers }
```