# activerecord - how to get all column of joined tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

After reading   : [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#using-array-hash-of-named-associations)

I still don't get it.   in console:

```
puts Category.joins(:posts)
```

It perform join or left join on Category and Post.

However, all data returned is just columns in Category table.  How to  also get those column data in Post. ?

should I  make another model to achieve this ?

after reading: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566521/rails-joins-and-include-columns-from-joins-table)
Is find_by_SQL is the only way ?  I want ActiveRecord way if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: You should be more specific about what you try to achieve. If you want it "the Active Record way", you shouldn't even talk about "columns" because you manipulate Objects, not tables. If you really need the raw data, you can use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all( 'SELECT...')`, this will return you an array of hashes (no model instanciation). [the documentation is here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-select_all)

Comment: thanks, I'm using this way now: ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all( Category.joins(:posts).to_sql ))     , is this way being too nasty ?

Comment: No problem. However, if you really want to work the ORM way, you should only use these kind of tricks for really complex SQL queries. For such a trivial problem, i'd use @abhishek's solution + `includes` instead. Why bother using an ORM if you don't code in an OO way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get columns in posts tables by doing further querying, something like -

```
Category.joins(:posts).collect{|category| category.posts.map{|post| post.attributes.merge(category.attributes) } }
```

This will give you a giant list of post and category attributes merged together for each Category.

But the point of doing the join on Category is to get a set of Categories that have certain follow certain join criteria. If we take the next example in the same guide,

```
Post.joins(:category, :comments)
```

This also gives you a list of Posts only, but the list contains only the posts that follow the join constraint, which is, they all have a category and a comment.

Comment: beware, the `collect` will likely result in a N+1 query problem. To avoid this, use `includes`. see [the RoR guides on eager loading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)

Comment: Doesn't Post.joins(:category, :comments) returns a post multiple times, if it has more than one category and/or more than one comment?

Answer (score 8):

You can try select() method:

```
Category.select("categories.*, posts.*").joins(:posts)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.  This can't work.  It still only returning "categories.*" . Ever though the SQL generated is " SELECT categories.*, posts.* from ...

Comment: How do you check if it's working? I've just tested it, works fine for me.

Comment: I run this command in "rails console".  Using puts and ap(awesome print):

puts Category.select("categories.*, posts.*").joins(:posts)
It just return #<Category:0x0000000528c170> object. And only column of Category inside.

Comment: this method works if you name each column in your `select` statement, and then if you invoke the column name as a method on the instantiated objects (these will be marked readonly, btw, [see the guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields)). However, this method has always seemed a bit hackish to me : if you have columns with identical names in your two models, this will mess things up, save for using an alias. As i said, if you need the raw data, use `select_all` or even `select_row`.

Comment: agree, same named columns is a problem

Comment: or `Category.select('*').joins(:posts)`

Comment: this query returns records where the ids are `Post` ids. In other words, `id` and `post_id` of the returned records are the same for me. It seems like `Category` ids were substituted with `Post` ids. Is it suppose to be like that?