# Rails (Active Record) - return a list of all the fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

1)How do I get a list of all the fields from a model?

2) How do I get a list of all the fields from a model with a bunch of inner and left joins? (as when I look at the object, I only see the main returned object. I know the fields are accessible, but they do not appear in the object returned.

I noticed, I use `.attributes` and it will return all the fields, and any aliases from my sql select, but I can't have any of the SQL aliases returned. Or I need a way to identify them.

Answer (score 0):

For question 1 you'll find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289557/how-do-you-discover-model-attributes-in-rails)

For question 2 you'll maybe find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463211/activerecord-how-to-get-all-column-of-joined-tables)

Answer (score 0):

See [ActiveRecord::Base.columns_hash](https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.1.1/ActiveRecord%2FBase.columns_hash).

`Post.columns_hash # => ["id", "user_id", "body"]`