# How can I write two scopes that have colliding joins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope, named-scope

Let's say I have the following model:

```
# video.rb
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :collection_videos, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :collections, :through => :collection_videos
  named_scope :in_collection_one,
              :joins => :collection_videos,
              :conditions => "collection_videos.collection_id = 1"

  named_scope :in_foo_collections,
              :joins => :collections,
              :conditions => "collections.foo = true"
end

# collections.rb
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :videos, :through => :collection_videos
  has_many :collection_videos, :dependent => :destroy
end

# collection_videos.rb
class CollectionVideos < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :collection
  belongs_to :video
end
```

If I make the following call:

```
Video.in_collection_one.in_foo_collections
```

I will get an error after ActiveRecord has constructed the SQL query complaining about doing multiple joins - it will attempt to join on :collection_videos twice (wrong, should only join once), and :collections once (this is correct). This is likely caused by a bug in rails but I'm wondering if there is a way around it.

Note: I am using Rails/ActiveRecord version 2.3.2

Answer (score 0):

Could you use `:include` instead of `:join`?  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208636/rails-include-vs-joins) for an example of someone using `:include` to do joins.

Comment: The same issue occurs as Rails defers to doing an inner join on an :include. I think its a bug in Rails where the version is less than 2.3.5