# Rails ActiveRecord helper find method not eager loading association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, eager-loading

I have the following models: Game and Pick. There's a one to many association between Game and Pick. There's a third model called Player, a Player has many Picks.

There's a method in the Player class that finds a pick for a given game or creates a new one if it doesn't exist.

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :picks

  def pick_for_game(game)
    game_id = game.instance_of?(Game) ? game.id : game
    picks.find_or_initialize_by_game_id(game_id)
  end
end
```

I want to eager load the games for each pick. However if I do

```
picks.find_or_initialize_by_game_id(game_id, :include => :game)
```

It first fetches the picks when this query is run (the method is run multiple times), then fetches the games as each pick is accessed. If I add a default_scope to the Pick class

```
class Pick < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :player
  default_scope :include => :game
end
```

It still generates 2 select statements for each pick, but now it loads the game right after the pick, but it still doesn't do a join like I'm expecting.

```
Pick Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "picks".* FROM "picks" WHERE "picks"."game_id" = 1 AND ("picks".player_id = 1) LIMIT 1
Game Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "games".* FROM "games" WHERE ("games"."id" = 1)
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to do a join? That's not what you're telling it to do.

Comment: @Andrew, so `:include` is not the same as doing a fetch join? I'm coming from an NHibernate background so I am expecting it to do one call with a join and eagerly load the associated entity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, [`find`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html#method-c-find) doesn't support having `include` or `join` as a parameter. (As mipsy said, it doesn't make sense for find to support `include` as it would be the same number of queries as loading it later.)

Second, `include` eagerly loads the association, so something like

```
Person.includes(:company)
```

is roughly equivalent to doing:

```
Person.all.each { |person| Company.find(person.company_id) }
```

I say *roughly* equivalent to because the former has `O(1)` (really two) queries whereas the latter is `O(n)` queries, where `n` is the number of people.

A join, however, would be just one query, but the downside of a join is you can't always use the retrieved data to update the model. To do a join you would do:

```
Person.join(:companies)
```

You can read more on [joining tables in the Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables).

To sum up, joining isn't eagerly loading because it's not loading the association, it's loading both pieces of data together at once. I realize there's a weird fine line between the two, but eagerly loading is getting other data preemptively, but you wouldn't be getting that data later via a join, or you'd have already gotten it in your original query! Hope that makes sense.

Comment: So just to be clear, the statement `Person.join(:companies)` returns the Person object with the the companies loaded?

Comment: `Person.join(:companies)` will run the query `SELECT people.* FROM people INNER JOIN companies ON people.company_id = companies.id`

Comment: [This question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208636/rails-include-vs-joins) may be of help to you.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way it's meant to work, I think. Eager loading is primarily used to make iterations over large collections of models more efficient by fetching them all at once-- it won't make any difference if you're just dealing with a single object.