# Automated way to select all columns of joined table in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

Wondering with the upgrade to Arel, if ActiveRecord yet supports an automated way to select in the columns from joined tables, without having to explicitly list them in a select clause.

Given I'm joining the `users` table to `posts`, Would like to be able to do something like this in a more succinct manner:

```
  scope :select_user,
    select("posts.*, " + User.columns.map{|c| 
      "users.#{c.name} user_#{c.name}"}.join(','))
```

So, I want to automatically select the fields from user so that I get say

```
Post.joins(:user).select_user.first.user_name
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what you actually want here is to use `includes` if you want to access the association's attributes after the query is complete. So the same query would be

```
Post.includes(:user).first.user.name
```

This will result in two queries, one `select * from users` and one `select * from posts where posts.user_id in (id1, id2, id3...)` (assuming `post belongs_to user`) which may be a performance hit in a particular situation, but may be worth it from a syntax standpoint. In some cases it may even be faster [Rails :include vs. :joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208636/rails-include-vs-joins).

Arel will also intelligently use a `join` if you add a restriction operator to the query e.g. `Post.includes(:user).where('users.name = "Bo Bob"')` will do one query with a `join` and also enable you to use the associations on the resulting `Post` object.

Comment: https://github.com/ntalbott/query_trace is very useful while developing to see what sql queries are generated by each rails command.

Comment: my question is actually how to select all the fields of post and user that joined, and some of the field name is the same. post.name and user.name

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do it with 'joins':

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  scope :select_user, joins(:user).where('users.name = "Mary"')
  ...
end
```

or with a param:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  scope :select_user, lambda {|user_name|
    joins(:user).where('users.name = ?', user_name)
  }
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't show the join--the question is more about how to automatically select the fields from the joined table.