# Counting associated records in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to get the number of comments from each of the posts in the database. The following, however:

```
Post.includes(:comments).group("posts.id").count("comments.id")
```

raises the mysql error "Unknown column comments.id", since the generated sql seems to completely ignore the includes():

```
SELECT COUNT(comments.id) AS count_comments_id, posts.id AS posts_id
FROM `posts` GROUP BY posts.id
```

Interestingly, replacing includes() with joins() will produce working sql:

```
Post.joins(:comments).group("posts.id").count("comments.id")

SELECT COUNT(comments.id) AS count_comments_id, posts.id AS posts_id
FROM `posts` INNER JOIN `comments` ON `comments`.`post_id` = `posts`.`id`
GROUP BY posts.id
```

but the above query excludes all posts with 0 comments, which is not what I want. What I do need is to produce the following SQL (but without writing SQL, he he he)

```
SELECT COUNT(comments.id) AS count_comments_id, posts.id AS posts_id
FROM `posts` LEFT OUTER JOIN `comments` ON `comments`.`post_id` = `posts`.`id`
GROUP BY posts.id
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `includes` method will not do a join in all cases but rather batch-fetch the association for performance reasons (see [Rails :include vs. :joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208636/rails-include-vs-joins)).

What you need to do is a joins and you where almost on the correct path but got the group clause a bit wrong:

```
Post.select("posts.*, COUNT(comments.id) as comment_count").joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN comments ON (comments.post_id = posts.id)").group("posts.id")
```

Note that this solution has the benefit or actually returning Post objects (using `.count()` returns a Hash on my Rails 3.2) so you can loop through actual post objects in your view and also access the property `comment_count`.

Comment: Right, but the INNER JOIN excludes all posts without comments. What I need is the complete list of posts, with the calculated field (i.e. comment_count) set to 0 when appropriate

Comment: Please see my own answer to see what I mean. Adding the explicit LEFT JOIN to your solution does not seem to work. All results with 0 comments end up aggregated into one, not sure why.

Comment: Because it's grouping by comments.id. Since all comments that don't have comments have comments.id null they get added up. Just change the group clause to `posts.id` and it should be fine..
I updated the answer

Comment: Syntax needs fixing (missing parenthesis at posts.id):
`Post.select("posts.*, COUNT(comments.id) as comment_count").joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN comments ON (comments.post_id = posts.id)").group("posts.id")`

Comment: Thanks @Vertaxe fixed it.

Answer (score 11):

This problem is actually way simpler nowadays:

```
Comment.joins(:post).group(:post_id).count(:post_id)
```

This will give you a map of `{<post_id> => <count of comments>}`

Comment: Actually, no. Your code generates an `INNER JOIN`, which by definition excludes posts without associated comments. Thus, posts with zero comments are not retrieved.

Comment: true. Since an inner join query is more efficient than outer join (by definition), i back fill the 0 records in ruby which is O(n) and quite fast. You can debate that null filling records in ruby might be slower than the db though.

Comment: The counts can be sorted with:  Comment.joins(:post).group(:post_id).count(:post_id).sort_by {|_key, value| value}

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Post.select("COUNT(comments.id) AS count_comments_id, posts.id AS posts_id").
  includes(:comments).group("posts.id")
```

Comment: You have a typo: includes(:comments)

Comment: This simply returns an array of post models and the select clause is ignored (there is no COUNT in the generated query)

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is the hash of post counts: `{post_id1 => cnt1, post_id2 => cnt2, ...}` then forcing a left join on the association will work:

```
  Post.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN comments on posts.id=comments.post_id").
  group("posts.id").count("comments.id")
```

Answer (score 0):

For **rails 5 or above**, we have a activerecord method `left_outer_joins` & we don't need to write the join logic manually.

```
Post.left_outer_joins(:comments)
    .distinct
    .select('posts.*, COUNT(comments.*) AS comments_count')
    .group('posts.id')
```

Which produces:

```
SELECT DISTINCT posts.*, COUNT(comments.*) AS comments_count FROM posts 
LEFT OUTER JOIN comments ON comments.post_id = posts.id GROUP BY posts.id
```