# activerecord newbie; get all profiles with gender male/female?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, relation

Im trying to get all the @participants where gender is male or female. 
I have just surfaced AR and now digging into all the possibility's more but find it hard to get this query done.

- user (user_id) has_profile
- profile belongs_to user
- participants (participant_id) belongs_to user, profile

Im trying to get all the participants with participant_id where in there profile ( user_id ) they have gender = 'male' or 'female'

What would be the best shortest way to get the @participants_male filled with the results?

Im not sure how to get it out of the relations with the where statement, anyone could help me in the right direction? thx!

```
@participants_male = Participant.where(
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gender is a column in the users table? If so:

```
@participants_male = Participant.includes(:users).where("users.gender = 'male'")
```

**EDIT** - if gender is in the profiles table:

```
@participants_male = Participant.includes(:profiles).where("profiles.gender = 'male'")
```

I also suggest to check [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/181-include-vs-joins?view=asciicast) railscast to understand the difference between `joins` and `includes`, so you can decide what is better in your case.

Comment: Ok So tried this and reading on joins vs includes. you example seems logic but throws an "Association named 'profiles' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?" so its not associated for participant

Comment: There is something wrong with your associations. Can you please include the models in your question...

Comment: Still this isn't working I think i should update question with more details on models and relations have to do that tonight

Comment: yes, please clarify the relationship between participants and profiles, because you said `participant belongs_to profile` but you didn't state that `profile has_many (or whatever) participants`. How are they connected?

Answer (score 2):

The rails guides on [active record queries](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) is a good resource. Your query would look something like this:

```
@males = Participant.joins(:profiles).where('profiles.gender = "male"')
```

Or you can use `includes` instead of `joins`

```
@males = Participant.includes(:profiles).where('profiles.gender = "male"')
```

Take a look at [includes vs joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208636/rails-include-vs-joins) to see which is appropriate for your particular case.