# Rails 3: nil error when attempting to display attribute of association with includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So, I'm a Rails newbie and may be missing something obvious, but I'm a bit flabbergasted as to why I'm getting a NoMethodError when I attempt to eager load an association using .includes.

Here's my code:

**forecasts_controller.rb**

```
def show
    @forecast = Forecast.find(params[:id])      
    @forecast_projects = Project.includes(:project_type).where("forecast_id =?", params[:id])
end
```

**_project.html.erb** (this file is a collection partial rendered in the Forecast action)

```
<%= project.project_type.title %>
```

For some reason, this produces the following error:

> NoMethodError in Forecasts#show
>
> Showing /path where line #1 raised:
>
> undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass

Oddly enough, if I change **forecasts_controller.rb** to...

```
def show
    @forecast = Forecast.find(params[:id])      
    @forecast_projects = Project.joins(:project_type).where("forecast_id =?", params[:id])
end
```

Suddenly everything starts working perfectly. Can someone help me figure out what I'm missing here (and excuse my lack of experience)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not work because there is one (or more) `project` having no `project_type` associated.

The big difference between `joins` and `includes`:

- `joins` retrieve **only** the records that have at least 1 association
- `includes` retrieve the records and load their association if it exists

[Rails :include vs. :joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208636/rails-include-vs-joins)

That means when you call:

```
@forecast_projects = Project.includes(:project_type).where("forecast_id =?", params[:id])
# loads all the projects AND their associated project_type if exists
@forecast_projects = Project.joins(:project_type).where("forecast_id =?", params[:id])
# loads all the projects HAVING at least 1 project_type associated
```

To clearly see the difference, try this:

```
Project.includes(:project_type).count # total number of entries in projects table
Project.joins(:project_type).count # number of projects having at least 1 project_type
```

**To fix your problem,** you can `try` to display the title of the associated `project_type` if it exists:

```
<%= project.project_type.try(:title) %>
# will print the project_type.title if exists, prints nothing if project_type.nil?
<%= project.project_type.try(:title) || 'No ProjectType for this Project' %>
# will print the string if project_type is nil
```

Comment: Thanks! That was super helpful. I appreciated the explanation of the core problem, as well as the additional introduction to the try method.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least one project without `project_type`. When you use `includes` rails selects all records and fails on the one without `project_type`. When you use `joins` it selects only those with `project_type`, **but doesn't include them**.

To fix the problem you better find the `bad` record and add the `project_type` to it and add validation to avoid this error in future. But if it's ok to have projects with blank `project_type` then use both `joins` and `includes` like `Project.joins(:project_type).includes(:project_type)`.