# activerecord where clause on relation belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm not strong in sql and relatively new to rails.  The

```
Case
  attr_accessible client_id
  belongs_to Client

Client
  attr_accessibe name
  has_many Cases
```

I can query directly by client_id and get a record back as expected

```
Case.where(client_id: 1)
```

But I would like to query by client.name

```
Case.where(client.name => "Foo")
```

This give me an error that tells me that client is not a method of case.

```
Undefined method or local variable
```

Ultimately, what I'm trying to do is very simple: get the first Case that belongs to client "Foo".  The query I would expect to use is this.

```
Case.where(client.name => "Foo").first
```

What should it be?

Comment: `Case.joins(:client).where(clients: { name: 'foo' })` is what you are looking for -- pay attention to the plural/singular: in the joins/includes, use the same name as the relations was declared in the model ; in the where clause, always use the pluralized version of the relation (don't ask me why)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
Case.joins(:client).where(clients: { name: 'foo' })
```

This query will joins the clients on the case table (eliminates the Cases without any client associated) and add the where clause `"where clients.name = 'foo'"`

**In human language**, this query does:

> Get the Cases having at least one Client having the name **strictly** equal (*case-sensitive*) to '*foo*'

---

**Pay attention** to the plural/singular:

- in the joins/includes, use the same name as the relation is declared in the model
- in the where clause, always use the pluralized version of the relation (actually the table's name)

---

**Additionnal informations:**

- You can use an array of values in the where clause:

  ```
  Case.joins(:client).where(clients: { id: [1,2,5] })
  ```
- Difference between `.joins` and `.includes`: [Rails :include vs. :joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208636/rails-include-vs-joins)

Comment: Ok well this answered my immediate question but created another.  thanks.  will link to that one from here.

Comment: The plural/singular issue is actually about two completely independent things. `joins`/`includes` refer to _how your association is called in Rails_ (here it's `:client`), whereas within `where` you're referencing _db tables and db columns_ (here the table is called `clients`). It is just convention/convenience to name them the same.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're doing it may be easier to go about it this way:

```
Client.where(:name => "foo").first.cases
```

This will return all the cases for the client.