# Rails ActiveRecord Join Confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In the console this code:

```
Patient.joins(:notes,:recordings).find(1)
```

Returns

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Patient with id=1
```

Which is bizarre because in the same console `Patient.find(1)` works without any issue and retrieves the record of the patient with id 1.

My understanding is that I should be able to do:

```
a = Patient.joins(:notes,:recordings).find(1)
a.notes
a.recordings
```

And a.notes should return all the notes associated with the patient with id 1 and same for a.recordings. It's clear I'm missing something here...any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because rails does `INNER JOIN` by default. your patient `1` doesn't have either `notes` or `recordings`

If can do a left join instead.

```
Patient.joins("LEFT JOIN notes on notes.patient_id = patients.id")
       .joins("LEFT JOIN recordings on recordings.patient_id = patients.id")
       .find(1)
```

or load the patient and then load the associations

```
 a = Patient.find(1)
 a.notes
 a.recordings
```

Comment: change find(1) to `first` ?

Comment: When the id doesn't exist is there a way to make it return an empty association rather than throw an error?

Comment: A better solution would be Patient.includes(:notes, :recordings).find(1)

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in include type functionality (for eager loading). See: [Rails :include vs. :joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208636/rails-include-vs-joins)