# Includes not allowing outer join and count on child table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :registrations

  delegate :count, to: :registrations, prefix: true
end

class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
end
```

In my Courses index view I show a count of Registrations for each record. What is best practice for this? Using includes(:registrations) with the delegated registrations_count method looks slower (in the console) than doing a database count in the main query.

I want to show all records, so I can't use an INNER join(). Using includes() as below gives the error `PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "registrations.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function` I tried adding a where clause on :registrations to this but it still errored:

```
Course.includes(:registrations).group("courses.id").select("courses.*, COUNT(registrations.id) as registrations_count")
```

Is it right to have to specify the outer join as follows?

```
Course.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN registrations ON registrations.course_id = courses.id').select('courses.*, COUNT(registrations.id) as registrations_count').group('courses.id')
```

This last query does work but it feels what I'm doing should be fairly standard so I'd like to be sure I'm taking the right approach in general.

Answer (score 4):

> In my Courses index view I show a count of Registrations for each record. What is best practice for this?

`counter_caching` is the best option for counting `association` objects. A counter cache in Rails is just an additional column that tracks the number of associated models.

You just have to do this

```
belongs_to :course , counter_cache: true
```

And then you can simply do this

```
@course.registrations_count
```

Learn more in [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column)

Looks like you are missing the difference between `includes` vs `joins`, [Learn here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208636/rails-include-vs-joins)

For me this is good.

```
Course.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN registrations ON registrations.course_id = courses.id').select('courses.*, COUNT(registrations.id) as registrations_count').group('courses.id')
```

Comment: I know the includes v joins difference just surprised the left outer join needs to be written explicitly here. But not if using counter_cache :) thanks. Looks like it would be accessed via a @course.registrations_count column though, not registrations.size?