# my active record query causing slow loading times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a sidebar on my app where I list customers with "open" tickets. When there are a lot of customers with open tickets, my site runs really slow. Upon examining the logs, it seems the lag is coming from the sidebar. Here's the query:

```
@sidebar_customers = current_user.company.customers.open_or_claimed.where("user_id = ? OR user_id IS NULL", current_user.id).order(aasm_state: :asc)
```

and this is how I display the sidebar:

```
  - @sidebar_customers.each do |customer|
    %li#sidebar-customer{:class => "#{active_state_class(customer)}"}
      = link_to raw("<i class = 'menu-icon fa #{claimed_class(customer)}' id = 'icon-cust-#{customer.id}'></i><span class = 'mm-text'>#{customer.full_name}</span>#{'<span id = "open" class = "label label-success pull-right">open</span>' if customer.open?}#{"<span id = 'new-cust-#{customer.id}' class = 'label label-danger'>new</span>" if customer.not_viewed_count > 0 && customer.claimed?}"), customer, id: "cust-#{customer.id}"
```

how can I make this faster? am i doing something wrong?

EDIT: also, this seems to be making the site slow as well:

```
@messages = current_user.company.messages.find(:all, :order => "id desc", :limit => 25)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not surprising since `current_user.company.customers` does SQL joins on the users table, the companys table and the customers table. And SQL joins are expensive (time consuming). As you noticed the performance of the joins decreases significantly with increase in data (customers in this case).

There are many ways to optimize the performance here.

First experiment with eager loading of data. See the section on **Eager Loading Multiple Associations**
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Next review this SO thread on differences between includes and Joins on performance.
[Rails :include vs. :joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208636/rails-include-vs-joins)

Be sure to review the SQL generated in the log file as you experiment. See if you can eliminate any unwanted joining.

Other usual things to speed up queries: Add indexes to the tables. Reduce the data returned by adding more constraints (where conditions).