# how to use LIKE in included relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel

I want to use search condition with included relations, just like below

```
Post.includes(:tags).where( tags: { title: '%token%' }).all
```

The `posts` and `tags` table has been associated with a 3rd table named `post_tag_relations`.
The schema is like below:

```
posts
 id: pk
 title: string
 content: text

tags
 id: pk
 title: string

post_tag_relations
 id: pk
 tag_id: integer
 post_id: integer
```

The syntax only works with equal condition, I really dont know how to use `LIKE` search condition.

When using `Post.joins(:tags)` and `Tag.area_table[:title].matches('%token%')` it will works fine, but some post that has no tags will not be fetch out.

Could anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

---

**UPDATE:**

The Rails version is 4.1.

I want to search the post like `posts.title LIKE '%token%' OR tags.title LIKE '%token%'`, so if  use `Post.joins(:tags)` will not be functional if some posts have no tags. So I need use `Post.includes(:tags)` instead.

---

**UPDATED AGAIN:**

looks cannot use one-query to fetch, so I had already try another database schema...

Comment: so which final condition wish you to implement? Posts with tags matched, and with no tags?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ thanks for your reply, I have updated the detail.

Comment: Can you show the schema for your tables? Does both your table tag and post have column 'title'

Comment: @AaditiJain yes, both `posts` and `tags` table has column `title`.

Comment: not quite understood, if you try matching over tag's title, for what do you need the posts without tag?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ need search matched title, content or tags.title. so it's an `OR` condition, not `AND`

Comment: which db have you use?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ MySQL db.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Post.includes(:tags).where( "tags.title LIKE ?", "%#{token}%" )
```

could work.
(The syntax might be a little wrong, sorry, but you get the idea)

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this:

```
Post.includes(:tags).where(Tag.arel_table[:title].matches('%token%').or(Tag.arel_table[:post_id].eq(nil)))
```

Comment: @Francis.TM have you a column named `title` in the `tags` table?

Answer (score 0):

Since [ruby-on-rails-2](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-2) the [`joins` operation is used in all cases before the `includes` operation during performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1208723/446267), but since `includes` uses `LEFT OUTER JOIN` operator, you should use exactly it. May be you need also to use not `LEFT`, but `FULL` join. So try this with [arel](/questions/tagged/arel) gem:

```
class Post
   scope :with_token(token), -> do |token|
      re = Regexp.union(token).to_s
      cond = Arel.sql("title REGEXP ? OR content REGEXP ?", re, re)
      includes(:tags).where(Tag.arel_table[:title].eq(token).or(cond))
   end
end
```

Of course original condition could be replaced to use `LIKE` operator:

```
class Post
   scope :with_token(token), -> do |token|
      includes(:tags).where(arel_table[:title].matches("%#{token}%")
         .or(arel_table[:content].matches("%#{token}%")
         .or(Tag.arel_table[:title].eq(token))))
   end
end
```

**NOTE:** If there are some errors, provide please result SQL.