# How to get profiles containing at least all tags (has_and_belongs_to_many relation)

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

help me please to understand, what is going on here? I have profiles with **has_and_belongs_to_many** relation with tags. And I want to be able to filter profiles, that contains **at least all tags**, not any of them. How can I do it?

Im trying to do it this way:

```
  Profile.includes(:tags).where(tags: {id: array }).having('COUNT(tags) >= ?', array.count).group('profiles.id, tags.id')
```

But here I have really wierd results:

```
array = ['212', '213', '214']
=> ["212", "213", "214"]

profile.tag_ids
=> [212, 214, 213]

array = ['212', '214']
=> ["212", "214"]
irb(main):051:0> Profile.includes(:tags).where(tags: {id: array }).having('COUNT(tags) >= ?', array.count).group('profiles.id, tags.id')
  SQL (0.7ms)  SELECT "profiles"."id" AS t0_r0, "profiles"."user_id" AS t0_r1, "profiles"."description" AS t0_r2, "profiles"."created_at" AS t0_r3, "profiles"."updated_at" AS t0_r4, "profiles"."first_name" AS t0_r5, "profiles"."last_name" AS t0_r6, "profiles"."date_of_birth" AS t0_r7, "profiles"."gender" AS t0_r8, "profiles"."short_time_price" AS t0_r9, "profiles"."long_time_price" AS t0_r10, "profiles"."city" AS t0_r11, "profiles"."line" AS t0_r12, "profiles"."instagram" AS t0_r13, "profiles"."facebook" AS t0_r14, "profiles"."whats_app" AS t0_r15, "profiles"."we_chat" AS t0_r16, "profiles"."other_contacts" AS t0_r17, "profiles"."geo_unit_id" AS t0_r18, "tags"."id" AS t1_r0, "tags"."body_en" AS t1_r1, "tags"."body_ru" AS t1_r2, "tags"."tags_group_id" AS t1_r3 FROM "profiles" LEFT OUTER JOIN "profiles_tags" ON "profiles_tags"."profile_id" = "profiles"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "tags" ON "tags"."id" = "profiles_tags"."tag_id" WHERE "tags"."id" IN ($1, $2) GROUP BY profiles.id, tags.id HAVING (COUNT(tags) >= 2) LIMIT $3  [["id", 212], ["id", 214], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>

array = ['212', '213', '214']
=> ["212", "213", "214"]
irb(main):049:0> Profile.includes(:tags).where(tags: {id: array }).having('COUNT(tags) >= ?', array.count).group('profiles.id, tags.id')
  SQL (0.8ms)  SELECT "profiles"."id" AS t0_r0, "profiles"."user_id" AS t0_r1, "profiles"."description" AS t0_r2, "profiles"."created_at" AS t0_r3, "profiles"."updated_at" AS t0_r4, "profiles"."first_name" AS t0_r5, "profiles"."last_name" AS t0_r6, "profiles"."date_of_birth" AS t0_r7, "profiles"."gender" AS t0_r8, "profiles"."short_time_price" AS t0_r9, "profiles"."long_time_price" AS t0_r10, "profiles"."city" AS t0_r11, "profiles"."line" AS t0_r12, "profiles"."instagram" AS t0_r13, "profiles"."facebook" AS t0_r14, "profiles"."whats_app" AS t0_r15, "profiles"."we_chat" AS t0_r16, "profiles"."other_contacts" AS t0_r17, "profiles"."geo_unit_id" AS t0_r18, "tags"."id" AS t1_r0, "tags"."body_en" AS t1_r1, "tags"."body_ru" AS t1_r2, "tags"."tags_group_id" AS t1_r3 FROM "profiles" LEFT OUTER JOIN "profiles_tags" ON "profiles_tags"."profile_id" = "profiles"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "tags" ON "tags"."id" = "profiles_tags"."tag_id" WHERE "tags"."id" IN ($1, $2, $3) GROUP BY profiles.id, tags.id HAVING (COUNT(tags) >= 3) LIMIT $4  [["id", 212], ["id", 213], ["id", 214], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Profile id: 84, ...>]>

array = ['212', '213']
=> ["212", "213"]
irb(main):047:0> Profile.includes(:tags).where(tags: {id: array }).having('COUNT(tags) >= ?', array.count).group('profiles.id, tags.id')
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Profile id: 84, ...>]>

array = ['214', '213']
=> ["214", "213"]
irb(main):039:0> Profile.includes(:tags).where(tags: {id: array }).having('COUNT(tags) >= ?', array.count).group('profiles.id, tags.id')
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Profile id: 84, ...>]>
```

How is it possible? Maybe there is another way to got profiles, containing all provided tags?

db schema with middle table here:

```
  create_table "profiles_tags", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "profile_id"
    t.bigint "tag_id"
    t.index ["profile_id"], name: "index_profiles_tags_on_profile_id"
    t.index ["tag_id"], name: "index_profiles_tags_on_tag_id"
  end
```

migration with relation is here:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class CreateProfilesTags < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :profiles_tags do |t|
      t.belongs_to :profile
      t.belongs_to :tag
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: How do your models and migrations look like? Don't you have a "middle" table to relate profiles to tags and viceversa?

Comment: Yes, I have, of course. I have tables 'profiles', 'profiles_tags' and 'tags'. Added schema with middle table

Comment: and, as you can see, @SebastianPalma, relations works proper way, related tags can be returned, but not with this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
Profile.joins(:tags)                  # <= use `joins` instead of `inclused`
       .where(tags: {id: array })
       .having('COUNT(tags) >= ?', array.count)
       .group('profiles.id')          # <= Do not use anything tags related here
```

It is important to note the difference between `includes` and `joins`. Whereas `joins` always makes a database join `included` only makes a join under certain conditions, sometimes it simply makes two queries. Use `joins` when Rails must make a database join to make the query work and use `includes` when you want to fix a n+1 issue (see [Rails :include vs. :joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208636/rails-include-vs-joins)).

When you need both – a database join and a fix of the n+1 issue – then run the join query as a subquery:

```
# a new scope in the mode
scope :when_tags, ->(tags) {
  joins(:tags)
    .where(tags: {id: tags })
    .having('COUNT(tags) >= ?', tags.count)
    .group('profiles.id')
}

# the actual nested query with includes:
Profile.where(id: Profile.with_tags(array)).include(:tags)
```

Comment: What if you really need `includes`?

Comment: I updated my answer to address the `includes` vs. `joins` topic.

Comment: @SebastianPalma I updated my answer and removed the example that wasn't working.